# How to install Open Intro interactive course of Swirl in R language

Tags: r, swirl

I have downloaded the zip file required for installation and followed the instructions given on the site.

`install_course_zip("C:\\Users\\Sanket\\Downloads\\swirl_courses-master.zip\\", multi=TRUE, which_course="Open Intro")`

> error message:Error in unzip(path, list = TRUE) : 
>     zip file 'C:\Users\Sanket\Downloads\swirl_courses-master.zip\' cannot be opened

Answer (score 0):

We can install that cousera swirl package in two type

one is

```
install.packages("swirl")
```

another one is install by manually..

In rstudio right side some options are there like package, plot, file,help

there you need to go package>install>

there you need to choose package archive (install from )in first option
package>install>install from> package archieve(*.zip, *.tz)

then you can navigate the your zip folder then click install